# Difference between local variables and arguments

Tags: javascript

```
function addLinks () {
   for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
         link = document.createElement("a");
         link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
         link.onclick = function (num) {
             return function () {
                 alert(num);
             };
         }(i);
}}
```

A closure is created for each link; each closure has reference to the scope in which it was created. Since argument `num` has been updated on each loop, on `click` on the first link it should alert `4`. Isn't it?

Comment: Argument num is never updated, it's a new variable on each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all, each function call gets a fresh copy of the `num` variable so the first link should alert 0.

If you really want to have all the callbacks share the same variable... then just have them share the same variable (the wrapper "num" stuff was precisely to avoid this problem and let the callbacks be independent):

```
//now all the inner closures use the same "i" variable
//since the variable gets mutated by the for loop
//all links are going to print "5" after the loop ends.
for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
     link = document.createElement("a");
     link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
     link.onclick = function () {
         alert(i);
     };
}
```

BTW, this only happens because, unlike in other languages, JS doesn't have block scope for loop indices. The for loop behaves as if you had done

```
var i;
while(i < 5){
   //...
   i++
}
```

Comment: You should mention that JS has a functional scope, and `i` "lives" in the function, not on the loop (nor per iteration).

Answer (score 1):

No.

And because you're confusing a couple of things:

1. function arguments are local to a function (with a big "unless", saved for number 2)
   They are intended to alias an object (including arrays/functions), or a value, to the function's scope, under whatever name you choose.
   The goal is to allow you to rename your parameter to anything you want, for purposes of making the inner-code make sense, regardless of what you pass in as an argument from the outer code.
   This has nothing to do with scope.
2. variables in JS are passed by reference, if they are objects, and by value if they are scalars.
   The whole point of passing `i` into a new closure is that the ***value*** of `i` is being passed as the argument, rather than a ***reference*** to `i`, which is what happens if you ***don't*** include the closure.

If you were to pass an object, and the object was what had the `i` on it (`obj.i += 1`), then again, closure or not, each function would point to the same value of `i`, because they'd all share the same reference to the same object.

*objects* are passed by ***reference***, *scalars* are passed by ***value***.
Even though there are *technically* string and number objects, they are converted to the scalar values as soon as you aren't doing anything object-oriented with them, directly.

```
var i = 3,
    say_i = function () { console.log(i); };
```

versus

```
var i = 3,
    say_i = (function (val) { return function () { console.log(val); }(i));
```

The first one gives a ***reference*** to `i`.
When `say_i` is run, it looks at the value of `i` in real-time, and spits that into the console.

The second one has passed a ***value*** to the outer-scope of the returned function, aliased as the name `val`.
Because numbers are passed by value, and not by reference, `val` will always equal the same thing, unless changed from the inside.

You could also achieve this same result if you made a function one time, outside of the loop:

```
var add_log = function (el, val) { el.onclick = function () { console.log(val); }; },
    i = 0,
    el;

for (; i < ........) {
    el = ....
    add_log(el, i);
}
```

`i` is being passed by value, therefore all elements will have a different `val` in their scope table, therefore, every element will log a different number.